# VW Passat B8 - remove low beam bulb - pull, rotate or...?

Tags: vw, headlight, passat, bulbs

I'm learning to replace the low beam bulb (H7) on **VW Passat B8**. The access is under the wheel.

I got to the bulb but I'm not sure if I should just pull using the force or do I have to do something else now?

There are surprisingly almost no tutorials on this for B8 even if it's a very common car here.

[image]

What's the steps?

1. remove the cable (the black one)
2. remove the bulb by pressing the two points on the metal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically exactly as you are suggesting. Pull the black connector off the back of the bulb. Then once you have full access to the back of the bulb, press in on the small metal tabs holding the bulb in. This shouldn't take too much pressure to get the bulb to pop free. Use a small flat tip screwdriver, pushing gently on the tabs. Work one side at a time.

Note: Just watching a video, they were able to pop it free with their hands. Here's the videos for reference:

- https://youtu.be/ooIm4nszGb4
- https://youtu.be/XjHa9J3csTQ

Work in reverse to insert the new bulb, except you shouldn't need a screwdriver. It should just pop right back in. Ensure you **DO NOT** touch the bulb glass itself. Oils on your finger (or any other contaminants for that matter) will kill the bulb in the first couple hours of use.

Comment: Thank you, I saw these videos. I'll try it tomorrow.

Comment: Not sure if it's good but it went out with the bulb connected so I disconnected it then and it looks to be working. Thanks